# Phonegap plugin (Version >=3.0) to retrieve registered email address of an Android device

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, android-account

I need to get the registered email of an Android device within my Cordova App. I currently have a Cordova 3.3.0 app working; and I could only find the Cordova plugin for version 2.5 at [this place](https://github.com/seltzlab/AccountList-Phonegap-Android-Plugin)
This plugin is not compatible with the version I am currently using. Has anyone provided an updated plugin for this?

How to update this plugin which is built for 2.5, to make it compatible to 3.3.0?

The plugin actually needs permission from android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS

**UPDATE:** I did the following to the AccountList.java file

```
package com.seltzlab.mobile;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.content.Context;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;

public class AccountList extends CordovaPlugin {

private Context ctx;

public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
try {
JSONObject obj = args.getJSONObject(0);
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this.ctx);
Account[] accounts;
if (obj.has("type"))
accounts = am.getAccountsByType(obj.getString("type"));
else
accounts = am.getAccounts();
JSONArray res = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
Account a = accounts[i];
res.put(a.name);
}
return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, res);
} catch (JSONException e) {
return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
}
}
}
```

where, the original is -

```
package com.seltzlab.mobile;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;

public class AccountList extends Plugin {   

@Override   public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId)
 {      
try {           
JSONObject obj = args.getJSONObject(0);         
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this.ctx);           
Account[] accounts;         
if (obj.has("type"))                
accounts = am.getAccountsByType(obj.getString("type"));         
else                
accounts = am.getAccounts();            
JSONArray res = new JSONArray();            
for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {             
Account a = accounts[i];                
res.put(a.name);            
}           
return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, res);       
} 
catch (JSONException e) {           
return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);        
}   
}}
```

and my script in the HTML file is as follows -

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="accountlist.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function getAccs(){
        alert("get the Accounts function starts")

        cordova.define("com.seltzlab.mobile.AccountList")

        window.plugins.AccountList.get(
                {
                    type: 'gmail' // if not specified get all accounts
                }, 
                function (result) {
                    alert(res.length);
            for (i in res)
                alert(res[i]);
                },
                function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            );

        }
        </script>
```

I am getting an error saying AccountList is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try contact cordova plugin to retrieve registered email address from your Android device

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts

example

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {
    alert('Found ' + navigator.contacts.length + ' navigator.contacts.');
};

function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
};

// find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter   = "Bob";
options.multiple = true;
var fields       = ["displayName", "name","email"];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Dato'
I need the email of the device (registered email of the device). Not of any contact's.
Can we do that ?

Comment: why you want to do that?

Comment: this email will be sent to a service and that service uses this email for authentication purposes (an indication that the request came from an andriod deivice with this email address).